# Facebook Login Not able to load local resource (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication

I am building a native android application that requires Facebook authentication. The facebook login button was working before but now when the button is clicked, there is an onError callback that is called in my activity, and the stack trace says:

"[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (0)".

What's going on?

Comment: same issue here, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I don't remember what I did exactly, but check to see if your gradle dependencies have not changed.